# If the probability to see a dog in a 3 hour time frame was 60%, whats the probability of seeing a dog between 12pm-12.30pm?

Tags: probability

(assuming constant probability)

Now logically I tackled this as 60/3=20% for one hour so 10% for half an hour but it doesn't sit right with me. Is this correct?

Comment: A key term for research is "(homogeneous) Poisson process."

Comment: As a hint: by the same logic, what would the probability be for 6 hours?